# Amazon S3 - How to recursively rename files?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to fetch my files via the `s3.getObject()` method in my node.js backend.

Trouble is, upon uploading the files to my bucket, I failed to replace special characters, dashes, and white-spaces. So, any files that have a `Key` value of (e.g., a `Key` with the value of `10th Anniversary Party (Part 1) 1-23-04` has an endpoint of `10th+Anniversary+Party+(Part+1)+1-23-04`).

This becomes troublesome when trying to encode the URI for fetching. I'd like to replace all dashes, white-space, and special chars with a simple underscore. I've seen some possible conventions using the `aws-cli`, however I am unsure what the best command for this is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a program that:

- Lists the contents of the bucket
- Calls `CopyObject()` to copy the object to a new Key
- Calls `DeleteObject()` to delete the previous copy

Or, you could take advantage of the fact that the AWS CLI offers a `aws s3 mv` command that will Copy + Delete for you.

I often simply create an Excel spreadsheet with the existing names, and a formula for determining what name I'd like. Then, I create a third column with:

```
aws s3 mv [Column 1] [Column 2]
```

Use Copy Down on the rows to get all the `mv` commands. Then, copy the column of commands, paste them into the command-line and it will rename all the objects in Amazon S3! (Test with 1-2 lines first, in case there is an error in the formula.)

This might seem primitive, but it's a very quick way to make the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, John. I was able to solve this via a separte node.js file by `copying each object on s3, renaming it, and then deleting the previous object.